# Cant Query Hive Tables after Sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I imported several tables of a oracle db into hive via sqoop. The command looked something like this:

```
./sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//185.2.252.52:1521/orcl --username USER_NAME --password test --table TABLENAME--hive-import
```

Im using a embedded Metastore (At least i think so. i have not changed the default conf in that regard). When i do SHOW TABLES in HIVE, the imported Tables do not show up, but some Tables i've created for testing via the command line do. The tables are all in the same warehouse directory on the hdfs. It seems like the sqoop import is not using the same metastore.

But where ist it? And how can I switch to it when using the command line for querying?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the entire problem is in embedded metastore as HIVE will create it in case that it don't exists in user current working directory by default. And thus Sqoop will end up using different metastore than hive. I would recommend configuring MySQL as backend for metastore.